# I am kind of lost in what do I do from here in Propositional Logic Identities. Please help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

[My Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm0YH.jpg)

Please help. Also if you can suggest any alternative approach, that will be great. Thank You.

Comment: Could you format your work with [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Answer (score 1):

HINT

Use the law of

**Absorption**

$p \lor (p \land q) \equiv p$